# Shapely's Simplify does not simplify

Tags: python, shapely

I have a simple rectangle where one of the points is redundant. I'm trying to remove this point with simplify of the shapely package. This does not seem to work for the current example. Any idea why? Or does simplify not work when the points are nicely in order?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

#Example
test = [(20060.0, 20744.0), (20060.0, 16729.0), (19000.0, 16729.0), (19000.0, 22564.0), (20060.0, 22564.0), (20060.0, 20744.0)]

#Splitting coordinates to visualize
x,y = [], []
for i in test:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y, c='y', s=50)
plt.show()

#Trying to simplify polygon shape
poly = Polygon(test)
print(list(poly.simplify(0).exterior.coords))
```

The desired output is without the point `(20060.0, 20744.0)`

Comment: It could be because the point that needs to be removed is actually the `start` and `end` point of the Polygon. Seems to work fine if you "move" the point to be inside the list rather than at the start and end of it.

Comment: Well spotted. It’s tedious but I think I have to shift the arrays an index and compare lengths to make sure they’re all simplified…